# How to display Contact fields on Account object in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can anyone explain me how to display contacts fields on Account object Record page. I tried with one of my code, but i add this component in contact page it shows its contact details. but when i place it in Account object Record page it was not displaying.

js

```javacript
 import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
 import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 
 const FIELDS = [
     'Contact.Name',
     'Contact.Title',
     'Contact.Phone',
     'Contact.Email',
 ];
 
 export default class GetContactOnAccount extends LightningElement {
     @api recordId;
 
     @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
     contact;
 
     get name() {
         return this.contact.data.fields.Name.value;
     }
 
     get title() {
         return this.contact.data.fields.Title.value;
     }
 
     get phone() {
         return this.contact.data.fields.Phone.value;
     }
 
     get email() {
         return this.contact.data.fields.Email.value;
     }
 }
```

Html

```html
 <template>
     <lightning-card title="My Contact Record" icon-name="standard:contact">
         <template if:true={contact.data}>
             <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                 <p>{name}</p>
                 <p>{title}</p>
                 <p><lightning-formatted-phone value={phone}></lightning-formatted-phone></p>
                 <p><lightning-formatted-email value={email}></lightning-formatted-email></p>
             </div>
         </template>
     </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are querying Contact Object fields, not Account Object fields.

If you were to add error handling to your @wire'd method, you would get feedback from the console to better identify issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I could display contact fields in an LWC account form doing the following:

```
import ACCOUNT_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
const FIELDS = [ACCOUNT_NAME, {"fieldApiName":"FinServ__TaxId__pc","objectApiName":"Account"}];
```

// where "FinServ__TaxId__pc" could be any contact field